# How to serialize fields with objects they are reference to?

Tags: java, serialization

My class Message is the class-wrapper to File. I want to serialize Message, send it on server, than deserialize and get File. But when i deserializing, I get only File name? What i am doing wrong?

Class-wrapper:

```
public class Message implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private File file;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Deserializing code:

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        Message message = (Message)objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        String fileText = "";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(message.getFile());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        fileText = br.readLine();
```

When i trying to do this, i get FileNotFoundException. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: so how do you serialize ?

Comment: A `File` object represents a path *name*, not the content of any file or directory that may be accessible via that path.  And that's exactly what you see.  If you want the content instead then declare a field of suitable type for it, perhaps a `byte[]`, a `char[]`, or even a `List<String>`.  You probably want only one or the other. not both `File` and content.

Comment: @pirho `Message message = new Message();
        System.out.println("set path to the file:");
        String path = scanner.nextLine();
        message.setFile(new File(path));
        message.setId((int)(Math.random()*10));
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(message);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();`

Comment: please move that code to the question -edit- and see the answer by Kayaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `File` is just an abstract representation of a file, basically the path to the actual file. You can't serialize it, send it on the network, then act like the actual bytes of the file are present.

You need to actually read the bytes from the file and send them over the network. If you're working with small files, you could probably replace `File` with `byte[]` (and possibly add the filename or other metadata) and work with that.

If you're working with bigger files, you should probably consider something else than serialization, as the memory requirements become too large.

Comment: Ok, ty. Now its clear,. But how can i use wrapper? Its really necessary.

Comment: I need byte sequence handler in my Message class.

Comment: Wrapper? What are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about class Message with File field.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am so not attentive. You answered for this question too. Thank you@